# .Net core social login doesn't not working behind nginx

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nginx

I have a asp.net core 3.1 project. I included social login nuget package.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount/

Startup.cs below

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
.AddFacebook(options =>
{
options.AppId = serverSettings.FacebookLogin.AppId ;
options.AppSecret =serverSettings.FacebookLogin.AppSecret ;
})
.AddMicrosoftAccount(options =>
{
options.ClientId =serverSettings.MicrosoftLogin.ClientId;
options.ClientSecret = serverSettings.MicrosoftLogin.ClientSecret;
})
.AddGoogle(options =>
{
options.ClientId =serverSettings.GoogleLogin.ClientId ;
options.ClientSecret =serverSettings.GoogleLogin.ClientSecret ;
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
options.LoginPath = "/home/login";
});
```

Controller below

```
 [Route("signin")]
    public IActionResult SignIn() => View();

    [Route("signin/{provider}")]
    public IActionResult SignIn(string provider, string returnUrl = null) =>
        Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = returnUrl ?? "/Auth/ReturnUrl", }, provider);

    [Route("signout")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SignOut()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

This code working perfectly in local but, When i send this code ubuntu server. this is doesn't work. The server has nginx. Nginx working as reverse proxy. Forward the incoming request to localhost:5050

nginx.conf

```
server {
listen 443 ssl default_server;
location / {
  proxy_pass http://site:5050;
  proxy_redirect http://site:5050/ https://localhost:5050/;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
  proxy_connect_timeout 1;
  proxy_send_timeout 30;
  proxy_read_timeout 30;
}
error_log /var/log/nginx/api_error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/api_access.log;
ssl_certificate /etc/xxxxx;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/xxxxx;
}
```

In the last step is three platform throwing  same  error. After Authontication. When return to my app 
Error

Facebook

```
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "redirect_uri_mismatch"
```

Google

```
Body: {
"error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",
"error_description": "Bad Request"
 };
```

How can i solve tihs problem ? I think it's the problem. Forwarding incoming request to nginx in different url

Comment: Can you show the nginx conf?

Comment: I edited my post. I shared the nginx.conf @FrankNielsen

Comment: try remove the `proxy_redirect` line, dont think that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the error message from Google correctly, it's saying the redirect URI is incorrect. I'm guessing you configured the redirect uri for `https://localhost:5000/signin` or something along those lines while you were doing local development and testing.

Now that you are using an actual remote server with Nginx, your URI is no longer `localhost`. You need to configure the redirect URI to match that of your server's address that points to your application. You'll either need to use the actual public IP address of the server or the domain name, if you have one registered and have the DNS configured for it.

You should be able to reference the docs from each specific provider on how to configure it.

Comment: I writing the real adress in to google console. But forwading  to nginx http//:localhost:5050

Comment: @ismailERDEN Your browser can't navigate to `http://localhost:5050` on a remote server. You use the uri that the user will be re-directed back to after completing the login. Make sure your settings are matching across the application and identity provider.